# Modifying a particular item in a list of structures

Tags: c#

I have list of structure. I want to modify a particular data from the structure.
And the structure is at the particular index location of the List.

I want to do something like this:

```
struct sample
{
  int a;
  string name;
}

List<sample> list = new List<sample>();


for(int i=0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
  list[i].a = someotherlist[i].data;
}
```

Comment: And what is exactly your question?

Comment: Yes, this is not going to work with struct and lists. Perhaps a class and a list or a struct and an array.

Comment: @marc_s: The problem is pretty clear, no?

Comment: this is the error from compiler "Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Collections.Generic.List"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the list indexer creates a **copy** of the struct, i.e. it is really:

```
for(int i=0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
  var completelyIsolatedClone = list[i];
  completelyIsolatedClone.a = someotherlist[i].data;
}
```

The compiler is **preventing** you making an obvious mistake. The code you have uses the `get`, mutates a separate copy of the data, but *never puts it back* - so your change doesn't do anything useful. Note that the Mono folks think it would be nice if it worked your way, though: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Apr-11.html

Note that an *array* works differently; with an array you are touching the struct **in place**, so the following would work fine:

```
for(int i=0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
  someArray[i].a = someotherlist[i].data;
}
```

Another approach is to copy the data out (the get accessor), mutate it, and put it back:

```
for(int i=0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
  var completelyIsolatedClone = list[i];
  completelyIsolatedClone.a = someotherlist[i].data;
  list[i] = completelyIsolatedClone;
}
```

or better, acoid mutable structs completely, perhaps with a method that applies the change to a **new** copy:

```
for(int i=0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
  list[i] = list[i].SetA(someotherlist[i].data);
}
```

where `SetA` creates a **new** struct, like `DateTime.AddDays` etc, i.e.

```
public SomeType SetA(int a) {
    return new SomeType(this.X, this.Y, a, this.Z);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can't do it is because Sample is a `struct`, if you change it to a class then you can modify it. Structures are passed by value, that is, when a structure is returned by a method, a copy of the structure is returned, not the orginal structure. So when `list[i].a = someotherlist[i].data;` is run, you are actually modifying the copy and the orginal structure is not being changed. The compilers prevents you from doing this as it is probably not what you had intended.

You may look at this thread [Why couldnot I modify the value of item from Generic Collections) ?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/csharpgeneral/thread/6c925d84-2855-4a6d-a781-a269dd3b1eea)

Answer (score 0):

I just modified my code as bellow and it works fine for me

```
public struct test
        {
            public int data;
            public string name;
            public int port_index;
        }
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<test> look_up = new List<test>();
            test obj;
            obj.data = 1;
            obj.port_index = 0;
            obj.name = "aaaa";
            look_up.Add(obj);
            test obj1;
            obj1.data=3;
            obj1.port_index=1;
            obj1.name="sssss";
            look_up.Add(obj1);
            for(int i=0;i<look_up.Count;i++)
            {
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    test temp = look_up[i];
                    temp.data = 5;
                    look_up[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
```